404 URL No Longer Exists with REST API Call
When submitting a GET request with either Postman or boomi, I receive the following 404 error.
‘You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com’
In either tool, I can get the API token with OAuth2.0 using the resource owner credentials.
This is happening in our sandbox.
This is the base URL we are using for the REST calls: https://our-account.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Data/v60.0/
Below are the OAuth settings we have. Are these causing any of the problems?


That capital "D" in Data seems suspect. Try changing that to data.

That solves it, wow. Thanks

Salesforce's URI structure (at time of writing) always starts with /services/data/
So capitalizing the "D" is the issue
and the fix is to make it lowercase
URIs for other systems may or may not be case-sensitive, but the safe approach is to assume that they are.

Thanks again, I realized I was propagating my error by copying the bad URI.
